# How do i show record not found message when serach result not found in c# windowsforms

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=DESKTOP-28VA3GI;database=EMPLOYEES;integrated security=true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from emp where ename like '" + textBox1.Text + "%' or eno like '" + textBox1.Text + "%' or phone like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "e");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "e";
    }
    catch ( )
    {

    }
```

Comment: Where is your condition which consider `record count == 0`

Comment: I think 'if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)' is used to check if the dataset is empty.

Comment: i am loading employee records to datagridview based on ename,eno and phone number

Comment: @Bhushan Muttha Working fine thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get multiple table at once? If yes then you can use dataset else you can use datatable.

In case you opt for dataset you can find the number of rows in tables you are getting by using ds.Tables(i).Rows.Count. (i --> index of the table which you want to check).

In case you opt for datatable (dt) you can find number of rows by dt.Rows.Count.

Based on the result you can show your message.

Comment: Yes i did the same thing which you and @Bhushan Muttha has suggested to me